# Probability from hell: Calculate probability of drawing scrabble tiles in alphabetical order?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have 4 scrabble tiles: "A", "B", "C", and "D". I draw a letter at random and place it on the table, then draw a second and then a third, placing them down next to the previously drawn letter.

NOTICE! I'm only drawing 3 tiles, **not** four!

What is the probability that I draw the letters in alphabetical order?

The answer my book (in which, the probability of finding an honest answer is 0.1) is $\frac{1}{24}$.

The answer I through solving is $\frac{1}{6}$, and I, in no way, can figure whether I'm wrong or my book's answer section should surrender.

Comment: There are $4!=24$ possible orders, only one of which is $ABCD$ so...

Comment: Wait. I'm only drawing 3 tiles!

Comment: Ah, I missed that. In that case the answer is $\frac 1{3!}=\frac 16$ as you say.  But perhaps the source wanted you to draw four?

Comment: So the correct draws are: ABC, ABD, ACD, BCD.  That is, $4$ out of $24$. Result $4/24 = 1/6$.  The answer in the book is wrong...The other possibility is that it is intended to draw all four tiles, but the description is not clear, and he answer in the book is correct.

Comment: Perhaps it would be good if you could include the exact text of the original problem.  I expect that they intended to have you draw all four tiles, though perhaps they phrased that poorly.

Comment: @lulu I guess that's the only possible explanation :D

Comment: I agree with the $\frac16$ answer as you have stated the problem.  Sometimes in a later edition of a text book, a problem gets changed, and they forget to change the answer in the key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're only picking $3$, pick any tile first and throw it away (not literally!). You now have a $1:6$ chance.

Otherwise the book is asking a very trivial question.

Comment: That's what I got too! I guess the book must surrender :)

Answer (score 1):

- The probability you draw A first from A, B, C, D is $\frac14$
- The probability you draw B next from B, C, D is $\frac13$
- The probability you draw C next from C, D is $\frac12$

Then
$$\frac14 \times \frac13 \times \frac12 = \frac1{24}$$

Comment: Another way to interpret it.  Maybe this is what the book intended.

Comment: "A,B,C" / "A,B,D" / "A,C,D" / "B,C,D" are all in alphabetical order, aren't they?

Comment: @ElFlea If that is what the question intended then $\frac{4}{24} = \frac16$

Comment: @Henry So my answer is "supposedly" correct, right?

Answer (score 0):

What we are counting is the number of ways to choose four objects *without replacement*. Since only one of these will be in alphabetical order, it will be 1 divided by that.

The number of ways to choose four items without replacement is given by $4!=24$, and so the probability is indeed $\frac{1}{24}$.

An explanation of drawing without replacement:
We are choosing tiles one at a time. For our first choice, we can choose any of the four. For the second choice, we must choose one of the remaining three, and our third choice we will have to choose from two, and our final choice will be a single one. The number of total possibilities of this is $4*3*2*1=4!=24$. Only one of these possibilities is ABCD, and so the probability is $\frac{1}{24}$.

Comment: I don't think I get it! If I draw 3 tiles, I don't think your logic is right. Maybe I'm off?

Comment: @ElFlea I added a bit to my answer, let me know if it makes sense now

Comment: You don't pay attention to 3, THREE!, tiles! I only draw three tiles, NOT four!